# How to change TabItem of WPF TabControl from the UserControl Event?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, user-controls

In my project i.e in WPF there is TabControl with 4 tab. On the 4th Tab a UserControl that hold a DataGrid. I want to navigate the tha TabItem 1 i.e TabIndex 0 when click on the Row of DataGrid

Before above when my DataGrid is directly hosted on the TabItem 4 not a UserControl, I am able to navigate the TabItem but when I put the DataGrid in the UserControl and set this UserControl to TabItem 4 then not able to navigate when Click on the Row Of DataGrid.

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

As a simple solution :

Add an Event to your UserControl like "IClickOnRowEvent". Your control onwning tabControl has to subcribe to it and then do navigation logic

Comment: thanks to reply William. I am using DataGrid MouseLeftButtonDown event and tabCtrl.SelectedIndex = 0; to change the index of TabControl but not able to navigate.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand your issue. Can you give us a better description. when you click on your dataGrid row you want to go on the First Tab ? or you want to edit your datagrid then go to the first tab? try to be more explicit plz

Comment: I just want to go on the First Tab. I don't want to edit DataGrid. I was able to do this when my DataGrid on same Window but I moved DataGrid into UserControl and then using new UserControl instead of DataGrid. After this the existing functionality of moving to First Tab is not working.